# Magento 2.4.6 cweagans module not applying patches

Tags: magento2, composer, patches

I have installed **"cweagans"** module and added patch configurations to **composer.json** file but when I run **"composer install"** it's not applying the patch and it's not giving any error. Does anyone have any idea?

I'm using Magento version 2.4.6.

Cweagans reference : https://docs.cweagans.net/composer-patches/getting-started/installation/

Regards